# Is it possible to flash a photo for a single slide in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I am hoping to show a tikzpicture that overlays the whole frame for a single slide without having to go in and add  to every single other line that excludes the slide number I would like to have the picture show for. Is there a command to hide everything but one thing is a slide or overlay a picture for one slide and then have it disappear?

Thanks! I'm really not sure if it's possible and am already thinking I will likely need to do a lot of  additions...

Comment: I'm not sure to get it right but isn't [beamer overlays](https://www.texdev.net/2014/01/17/the-beamer-slide-overlay-concept/) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Here is one way to do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some title}
As you can see \only<.(1)>{\dots}%
\pause
\only<.(1)>{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)
 {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\pause
even ducks do not put pineapple on a pizza.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that you do not *need* `tikz` to do that but it is really easy to get going with `tikz`.